# Как добавить после каждой строки элемент в динамический двумерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Функция добавляет в конец динамического двумерного массива цифру 9.

Проблема в том, что она корректно работает только если матрица квадратная.

Часть кода:

```
    void addColEnd(int**& ar, int& refm, int& refn) {
    int **ar1 = 0;
    refn++;
    ar1 = new int*[refm];
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        *(ar1 + i) = new int[refn];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < refn-1; j++) {
            *(*(ar1 + i) + j) = *(*(ar + i) + j);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < refm; j++) {
        *(*(ar1 + j) + refn - 1) = 9;
    }
    delete[]ar;
    ar = ar1;
    for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < refn ; j++) {
            cout << *(*(ar + i) + j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: вопрос не понятен. сформулируйте правильно, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данные циклы

```
for (int i = 0; i < refm; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < refn; j++) {
                    ^^^^^^^^
        *(*(ar1 + i) + j) = *(*(ar + i) + j);
    }
}
```

ведут к неопределенному поведению программы, так как в предложении

```
        *(*(ar1 + i) + j) = *(*(ar + i) + j);
```

имеется попытка обратиться к несуществующим элементам массива `ar`, который имеет `refn - 1` колонок.

Такая же проблема имеется для цикла

```
for (int j = 0; j < refn; j++) {
    *(*(ar1 + j) + refn-1) = 9;
        ^^^^^^^
}
```

так как массив `ar1` имеет `refm` строк, а не `refn` строк.

Также вы не удаляете всю память, выделенную под исходный массив, что приводит к утечке памяти.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которач показывает, как эта функция может быть определена. Я назвал ее `appendArray`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void freeArray( int ** &a, size_t m )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) delete [] a[i];
    delete [] a;

    a = nullptr;
}

bool appendColumn( int ** &a, size_t m, size_t n, int value )
{
    int ** tmp = new int *[ m ];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) tmp[i] = new int[ n + 1 ];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        std::copy( a[i], a[i] + n, tmp[i] );
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ ) tmp[i][n] = value;

    freeArray( a, m );

    a = tmp;

    return true;
}       

int main() 
{
    size_t m = 2;
    size_t n = 3;

    int **a;

    a = new int *[m];

    a[0] = new int[n] { 1, 2, 3 };
    a[1] = new int[n] { 4, 5, 6 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    n += appendColumn( a, m, n, 9 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    freeArray( a, m );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль следующий

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
1 2 3 9 
4 5 6 9
```

Comment: Спасибо изменил, но массив выводится только квадратный (ввел 10 на 6, выводиться только 6 на 6) Сейчас изменю код.

Comment: @AdamHodovanets Значит изменили программу, не исправив все ошибки. Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: @AdamHodovanets И вы зря меняете свой ответ, внося изменения в соответствии с моими замечаниями, так как это вводит заблуждение читающих вопрос и ответ.